# Python eve and mongodb user access

Tags: python, authentication, flask, eve

I'm doing the Python Eve [tutorials on authentication and authorization.](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html#accounts-with-basic-authentication) In the settings.py file it specifies this block of code:

```
    # Let's just use the local mongod instance. Edit as needed.

    # Please note that MONGO_HOST and MONGO_PORT could very well be 
    left
    # out as they already default to a bare bones local 'mongod' 
    instance.
    MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
    MONGO_PORT = 27017

    # Skip these if your db has no auth. But it really should.
    MONGO_USERNAME = '<your username>'
    MONGO_PASSWORD = '<your password>'
```

But in the tutorial it sets up a separate 'accounts' collection in Mongo to handle users and accounts. It looks like it wants you to create a separate authentication process just for the python application, and not use Mongo's built in [user access features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). Is this correct, and is there a reason for this?

It seems to me that hardcoding a Mongo database user + password into a file on a server isn't so secure, and that it'd make more sense to try to use Mongo's own authentication stuff as much as possible. I know pymongo has some tools to work with Mongo users but I wanted to check if there was a good reason for doing it this way before I go diving into that.